# XBee WiFi: Does it work on the Wireless Proto Shield?

Tags: wifi, shields, xbee

I have been following this tutorial by sparkfun

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/internet-datalogging-with-arduino-and-xbee-wifi

and I have XBee Wifi but not the Shield of SparkFun. I have the Wireless ProtoShield which is provided by Arduino.cc

I wonder if both are compatible with each other?
Thank you in advance.